# Static NAT - Cisco Packet Tracer

Tags: cisco, packet-tracer

I have configured what I think is Static Nat on my "NAT Router". I have attached an image of my network topology.

However when I test the connection between the server on the inside network and the agent PC on the outside network it seems something regarding the NAT seems to be wrong as it won't access with the nat address?

I do need to set a NAT router statement to accept and rout any IP from the internet with any subnet mask to (FA0/1) which im struggling with, because this isn't set up could this be why? Does anyone know how I would implement this?

This is the coding which I have added for nat

`Ronald(config)#ip nat inside source static 172.31.0.100 74.125.20.100
Ronald(config)#inter
Ronald(config)#interface fas
Ronald(config)#interface fastEthernet 0/1
Ronald(config-if)#ip nat inside
Ronald(config-if)#exit
Ronald(config)#inter
Ronald(config)#interface fa
Ronald(config)#interface fastEthernet 0/0
Ronald(config-if)#ip nat outside
Ronald(config-if)#exit`

[image: network]

`Ronald#show ip nat translation
Pro  Inside global     Inside local       Outside local      Outside global
---  74.125.20.100     172.31.0.100       ---                ---`

**Router Configurations**

`Router#config t
Router(config)hostname Ronald
Ronald(config)#interface FastEthernet0/0
Ronald(config-if)#ip address 74.125.15.2 255.255.255.0
Ronald(config-if)#ip address 74.125.15.2 255.255.255.0
Ronald(config-if)#
Ronald(config-if)#exit
Ronald(config)#interface FastEthernet0/1
Ronald(config-if)#ip address 74.125.20.1 255.255.255.0
Ronald(config)#ip nat inside source static 172.31.0.100 74.125.20.100
Ronald(config)#inter
Ronald(config)#interface fas
Ronald(config)#interface fastEthernet 0/1
Ronald(config-if)#ip nat inside
Ronald(config-if)#exit
Ronald(config)#inter
Ronald(config)#interface fa
Ronald(config)#interface fastEthernet 0/0
Ronald(config-if)#ip nat outside
Ronald(config-if)#exit`

Comment: You can see the NAT status with "show ip nat translation"

Comment: it comes up with - Ronald#show ip nat translation
Pro  Inside global     Inside local       Outside local      Outside global
---  74.125.20.100     172.31.0.100       ---                --- (I have updated original post)

Comment: NAT seems to be set  up correctly.  Please edit your question to include the rest of your router configuration so we can see where else things may have gone wrong.

Comment: I've noticed the Agent PC wont connect to the NAT Router either, doesn't seem to have a connection but all the configurations are correct from what I can see so it might be a problem there.

Comment: please provide configuration of router, no issue with translation

Comment: the only configurations done on the router was the NAT and ip address's for the fast ethernets. I will add it to the existing post

Comment: You need a route to the 172.31.0.0 network.  How will the router know where to forward the traffic?

Comment: how would I implement that? sorry im new to all this

Comment: ip route <network> <mask> <next hop>

Comment: ip route 172.31.0.0 255.255.0.0 74.125.15.1

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure Static Route. `Ip route 172.31.0.0 255.255.255.0 74.125.15.1` In NAT router. Otherwise Router does not know how to reach to your 172.31.0.0 network

internal router: ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 74.125.15.2

Comment: whenever I try to test this it still says destination host unreachable. Do I need to add any static routes other than the one above? Or do I need to add anything onto the internal router aswell? I've noticed my agent pc is connecting to anything either. im in a big mess ahaha

Comment: You probably need a route on your internal router:  ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 74.125.15.2

Comment: I had typed wrong ip address and just now i edited and @RonTrunk's comment added to my answer to complete it.

Comment: thank you for your assistance! I have now got it all working however the only one that wont communicate successfully is the Agent PC communicating with the web server with the nat address of 74.125.20.100 - is there any clear reasoning for this?